# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: if

Tags: sql, oracle

New to SQL and can't figure out why I'm getting the above error in the code.

```
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM addresses WHERE address.upper() = 'EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.COM') THEN
    INSERT INTO addresses
                     (id, type, address
                     )
              VALUES ('123', 'UNREGISTERED', 'EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.COM'
                     );

END
```

Comment: Why do you insert numeric value as string?

Answer (score 0):

First, PL/SQL does not allow `EXISTS` as an `IF` condition.

Second, if you want to prevent duplicates, don't use `IF`!!! Let the database enforce the data integrity, with a unique constraint or index:

```
create unique index unq_addresses_addresses on (upper(address));
```

Third, the function is `upper()` and it is called as `upper(address)` not `address.upper()`.

And finally, do you really want addresses to be unique?  It would seem that different users or types might have the same address.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron try this insert:

```
INSERT INTO addresses (id, type, address)
SELECT '123', 'UNREGISTERED', 'EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.COM' FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM addresses WHERE UPPER(address) = 'EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.COM');
```